Reddit API returning 200 but no access_token
When I use the following URI in Postman, I am successfully getting the access_token back, but when I use the same URI in my .NET app, I am getting a 403 message.
https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token?grant_type=password&username=xxxx&password=xxxx
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.
EDIT: Thank you for the link ipodtouch0218. I have added some fields in the header.
Now i am getting a 200 status back but nothing in the Body.
Here is the code:
public void Index()
{
    string username = "xxxxx";
    string password = "xxxxx";
    string authString = $"{"xxxxx"}:{"xxxx"}";
    string base64AuthString = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authString));
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, RedditAuth);
    requestMessage.Headers.Clear();
    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent($"?grant_type=password&username={username}&password={password}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("basic", base64AuthString);
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "test-app");
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "*");
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    Console.WriteLine(requestMessage);
    var response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine(response);
    return;
}

}

Does this answer your question? Reddit API returns HTTP 403

Have you tried setting a user agent from a browser? Also, have you tried the same request from a different tool, e.g. Postman or curl? Having a correct API call example usually helps when implementing an integration

Yes, i have tried testing with Postman and i do get the body contents back along with the generated access_token. It's only through this console app that the access_token doesn't show up inside the Response..

I found a working solution here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/laonex/minimal_usage_example_a_c_console_app_script/
I had to add two things:


Install Reddit library from Nuget


Added this code in the header section:
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "test-app");


Thanks.
